# Why do I keep on looping after I've filled in book info and why doesn't it write in to a file?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, oop

Basically, it's an OOP task which creates a class called book. In the submain, there'll be a menu for the user to add new books/ view all book titles/ view all book authors and exit. I haven't got into the view all book titles and authors yet because at the moment I'm getting looped back again after I inserted the book's details. Which also prevents writing to a text file that will store previous books.

```
    '   Description: Making a menu that lets the user store their books info (like a librarian).
        Sub Main()
    'making a book using the attributes and methods
    Dim title As String = ""
    Dim datepublished As Date = #01/01/0001#    '   date is in month/day/year
    Dim pagenum As Integer = 0
    Dim isbn As String = ""
    Dim author As String = ""
    Dim amountbooks As Integer = 0
    Dim newbook As Book = New Book()
    Dim choice As String = ""

    'Writing and Reading a text file.
    'CreateText creates a text file and returns system.io.streamwriter object.
    Dim streamwriter As System.IO.StreamWriter
    streamwriter = System.IO.File.CreateText("C:\Users\Local_PC\Desktop\Try_oop_book\bookrecords.txt")



    'Making a menu for the client
    ' A While loop for the menu that checks the user's input
    While choice <> "1" Or choice <> "2" Or choice <> "3" Or choice <> "4"
        Console.Clear()
        Console.WriteLine("----------LIBRARY MENU----------")
        Console.WriteLine("[ 1 ]" & "Add New Book(s)")
        Console.WriteLine("[ 2 ]" & "View all Book Titles")
        Console.WriteLine("[ 3 ]" & "View all Authors")
        Console.WriteLine("[ 4 ]" & "Exit")
        choice = Console.ReadLine()
        If choice <> "1" And choice <> "2" And choice <> "3" And choice <> "4" Then
            Console.WriteLine("Please type in a valid input next time, press enter to retry again.")
            Console.ReadLine()

        Else
            'Using choice, it goes to check which menu the user typed in.
            If choice = "1" Then
                'The user has chosen 1 which is to add new book(s) to the menu system.
                'Setting the title of the book using mybook.setTitle
                Console.WriteLine("How many books do you want to add?")
                amountbooks = Console.ReadLine()

                Dim bookarr(amountbooks) As Book    'This will initialise after amountbooks has been entered. Prevents from getting invalid index number of 0.

                For x = 1 To amountbooks '  This loop will go over how many amount of books the user wants to add in to.
                    bookarr(x) = New Book()

                    Console.WriteLine("What is the title of the book?")
                    title = Console.ReadLine()      'This gives the value to store inside the variable 'title'
                    newbook.setTitle(title)      'This line will set that 'title' into array bookarr

                    Console.WriteLine("When is the book published?")
                    datepublished = Console.ReadLine()
                    newbook.setDatePublished(datepublished)

                    Console.WriteLine("How many page numbers are there?")
                    pagenum = Console.ReadLine()
                    newbook.setPageNum(pagenum)

                    Console.WriteLine("What is the ISBN(code) of the book?")
                    isbn = Console.ReadLine()
                    newbook.setISBN(isbn)

                    Console.WriteLine("Who is the author of the book?")
                    author = Console.ReadLine()
                    newbook.setAuthor(author)

                Next x
            End If
        End If
    End While

    streamwriter.WriteLine(newbook)

End Sub
```

Comment: There is no code there to write to the streamwriter until the loop exits, handle anything other than `choice = "1"` and no code to get a new choice after some books have been entered.  You should set `Option Strict On` and fire up the debugger: you will learn A LOT watching the difference between what really happens and what you thought would happen

Comment: Side note: In NET we use properties, not _setSomething_ methods.

Comment: `Dim newbook As Book = New Book()` and `bookarr(x) = New Book()` don't refer to the same book. But you proceed to do `newbook.setTitle(title)` etc. on the first one, not on the newly created one. So you never update `bookarr(x)`. It should be `bookarr(x).setTitle(title)` etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the while clause to replace 'Or' with 'AndAlso':

`While choice <> "1" AndAlso choice <> "2" AndAlso choice <> "3" AndAlso choice <> "4"`

In your current code if choice is 3 (for example) then it is not 1, 2 or 4 and the code will enter the while loop - in other words you have an infinite loop.

Comment: Thanks @VisualVincent - have edited answer to reflect that.